# How to write perfect query for join operation on two table?

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables. I wrote this query but don't show for table result
how write perfect query show table result?

```
  Taccess
 id   userid  groupid    accesstype
  1     2       1           1
  2     4       1           1

  Tgroup
   grugroupid       groupbname     userid  
       1               group-1       1
       2               group-2       2
       3               group-3       3
       4               group-4       4
```

I need this result for userid=1
I want show all groupid then show accesstype userid=1

```
  grugroupid         groupbname       accesstype
       1               group-1            1
       2               group-2            null  
       3               group-3            null
       4               group-4            null

     select grugroupid         , 
           userid ,groupbname     ,       
          (select AccessType from Access where   UserID=2 ) as dd,           
                 from  TLab_Info  
      union 
       select   id   userid  groupid    accesstype
          from   TLab_Access
```

Comment: Can you explain the relation between those tables? like foreign key..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

additional variant to already posted by `Raging Bull`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       g.grugroupid,
       g.groupbname,
       a.accesstype
FROM   Tgroup g LEFT JOIN
       Taccess a ON g.grugroupid = a.groupid
WHERE COALESCE(a.accesstype,1) = 1
```

test is here [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4bfa2/22)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT g.grugroupid,g.groupbname,a.accesstype
FROM Tgroup g LEFT JOIN
     Taccess a on g.grugroupid=a.groupid
WHERE (a.accesstype IS NULL) OR (a.accesstype=1)
GROUP BY g.grugroupid,g.groupbname,a.accesstype
```

Result:

```
grugroupid  groupbname  accesstype
----------------------------------
1           group-1     1
2           group-2     (null)
3           group-3     (null)
4           group-4     (null)
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4bfa2/11).